# 1. taint: Calling queryForObject. Reading data from the database, which is considered tainted

Tags: coverity, taint

I am getting taint issue in Coverity scan. Actually I am calling a function related to query. It gives the taint issue such that

1. taint: Calling queryForObject. Reading data from the database, which is considered tainted (The virtual call resolves to org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(java.lang.String, java.util.Map, java.lang.Class).)

I am not able to fix it. Can anyone help me how to figure it out?

I tried some validation. The code is below

```
`String fileSharePath=getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(query, namedParameters, String.class);`
```

The problem is shown near queryForObject.

Comment: The "Reading data from the database" message is just one event within a set of events that comprise the entire finding.  We need to see the rest of the events, and their associated code lines, to understand the issue.  There are some tips on navigating to other events in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72147179/2659307).