# suppress all occurrences of a certain coverity report anywhere

Tags: coverity

Somehow coverity does not like my way of indenting and I'm getting NESTING_IDENT_MISMATCH errors from all over the source code.

This had not the intended effect, as it made me ignore the daily reports from coverity.

I read that one can silence coverity by adding some attribute just above the line coverity is complaining about. But this would require an excessive amount of attributes (making the code unreadable for me).

Is there some way to silence certain coverity errors globally or at least anywhere below a certain source line?

Answer (score 0):

To disable a checker globally, use the `--disable` option to `cov-analyze` or `cov-run-desktop`, depending on how you are running the analysis:

```
$ cov-analyze --disable NESTING_IDENT_MISMATCH ...
```

or:

```
$ cov-run-desktop --disable NESTING_IDENT_MISMATCH ...
```

If the daily reports you refer to are being generated by someone else, you'll have to ask them to change the command line as indicated.

Related Synopsys support articles:

- [How do we make Coverity ignore an error?](https://community.synopsys.com/s/question/0D52H00004m37hLSAQ/how-do-we-make-coverity-ignore-an-error)
- [How to disable checkers whiling running cov-run-desktop?](https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/How-to-disable-checkers-whiling-running-cov-run-desktop)

As you mentioned, it is possible to suppress specific findings using code annotations, as described in an answer to [How can I disable coverity checking using code annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69596188/how-can-i-disable-coverity-checking-using-code-annotation), but that would not work well for findings that appear in many places, and there is not a way to suppress everything below a certain line.